# AngularFire $signInWithPopup compatibility with IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to authenticate on IE 11, but I receive the following error immediately after clicking my login button:

> "Authentication failed: Error: The popup has been closed by the user before finalizing the operation."

The error appears as soon as the signIn window opens, before it even has a chance to authenticate. I don't have this error with Chrome, Safari, or Edge. Only on IE 11. Is there some kind of workaround for this?

```
 function logIn() {
  return auth.$signInWithPopup("google")
  .then(function(firebaseUser) {
    if(firebaseUser) {
      is_user = true;
      return getToken(firebaseUser.user)
```

Link to full repo: https://github.com/jasunde/christian-cupboard/tree/4c3d4484e10a470ad3d454fd04a58c371d154356

Here's the specific file doing our authentication:

https://github.com/jasunde/christian-cupboard/blob/4c3d4484e10a470ad3d454fd04a58c371d154356/public/app/services/auth.factory.js

Comment: Auth-related errors in the JavaScript console? Does .catch() report any errors? Can you provide a complete, working repro of the problem? More due diligence to do here. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added links to the full repo as well as a link to the auth factory. Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: I tested the underlying signInWIthPopup in IE11-windows10 but couldn't get that error. Can you make sure you didn't disable any 3rd party cookies/data in your IE11 browser. After you do so, can you call the underlying firebase.auth().signInWithPopup so we can try to isolate the source of the problem (you will need to attach to a click). I speculate it should not be related to the angularfire library but want to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

There's a GitHub issue with similar symptoms [here](https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/issues/48).

It looks like it's either caused by running the website at localhost, or running it over HTTP (most communication between HTTP and HTTPS sites is blocked, such as the cross-window communication used by Firebase auth).

To quote the issue, the suggested solution is:

> You need to add your firebase auth domain url to IE's trusted sites:
>
> Internet Options > Security > Select Trusted Sites Zone > Click on "Sites" > Add your firebase url https://your-fb-name.firebaseapp.com